# Does this sum have an upper bound?

Tags: number-theory

If we have an infinite sequence of positive numbers whose sum is

$$
S = \sum_{i=1}^\infty a_n
$$

and

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0
$$

Can we draw conclusion that $S$ has an constant upper bound?

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean. If $S$ exists, $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$, but $S$ can be arbitrarily large. For instance, $\sum_{i=1}^\infty 2^{n-i}=2^n$.

Comment: Oh, that answered my question, thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning the comment into an answer:

If $S$ exists, it’s necessarily true that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$, but $S$ can still be arbitrarily large. For instance, $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty2^{n-i}=2^n.$$

Comment: Not only that, but $S$ might not exist even given $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$, e.g. the harmonic series.